# how to get the data lines to start at 0 and go to the first data point Flot

Tags: jquery, flot

[image]

At the beginning of the graph I would like the lines to go from 0 up to the first data points. Is this possible in FLOT.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.plot($('#placeholder'), [data]); // is the format
```

within `data` array you need to push an array like `[0,0]` at first. so for example the `data` array will look like:

```
[0, 0], [1, 10],...
```